# delete object network in cisco ASA with packet tracert

Tags: cisco-asa, packet-tracer, acl

I used 5506 as firewall and I am trying to delete object network I created and it gives error as ERROR: unable to delete the object configuration. object (inside-net-obj) is being used.

commands I used are:

```
ciscoasa(config)#interface GigabitEthernet 1/3
ciscoasa(config-if)#nameif inside1
INFO: Security level for "inside1" set to 0 by default.
ciscoasa(config-if)#security-level 100
ciscoasa(config-if)#no shutdown
ciscoasa(config-if)#exit
ciscoasa(config)#interface GigabitEthernet 1/4
ciscoasa(config-if)#nameif outside1
INFO: Security level for "outside1" set to 0 by default.
ciscoasa(config-if)#ip address 172.16.20.1 255.255.255.0
ciscoasa(config-if)#no shutdown
ciscoasa(config-if)#exit
ciscoasa(config)#interface GigabitEthernet 1/3
ciscoasa(config-if)#ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
ciscoasa(config-if)#exit
ciscoasa(config)#object network inside-net-obj
ciscoasa(config-network-object)#host 192.168.10.100
ciscoasa(config-network-object)#access-list out2in extended permit ip any object inside-net-obj
ciscoasa(config)#access-group out2in in interface outside1
ciscoasa(config)#no access-group out2in in interface outside1
ciscoasa(config)#no access-list out2in extended permit ip any object inside-net-obj
ciscoasa(config)#no object network inside-net-obj
ERROR: unable to delete object (inside-net-obj). object is being used.
ciscoasa(config)#show run | include inside-net-obj

object network inside-net-obj
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Run `show run | include inside-net-obj` and paste the output in your question please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's giving you that/those error(s) because removing that object would leave the access-list empty but still existing, which is not possible or allowed, and you can't delete an access-list like that (by just saying "no" on its only line).

What you need to do is:
`clear config access-list out2in`

This will disassociate the access-list with the interface and delete it, freeing up the object it's referencing.

Then you can delete the object itself by issuing: `no object network inside-net-obj`